# Asyntask serial executor

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When executing an `AsyncTask` in `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` mode: Is `onPostExecute()` (on UI thread) guaranteed to be executed straight after `doInBackground()` and before another started `AsyncTask` instance can get to call `onPreExecute()` for the new task?

I mean the serial executor mode - Does it guarantee that also the `onPostExecute()`/`onPreExecute()` callbacks are also always in order?

> This serialization is global to a particular process.

Is that what the above means?

Answer (score 0):

After `doInBackground()` the thread changes and `onPostExecute()` runs on UI thread. And after `doInBackground()` of first Task , the `doInBackground()` of another Task `doInBackground()` starts. So There is no chance of guarantee.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? They could have a lock somewhere preventing new onPreExecute from executing before onPostExecute() from previous run has finished, no?

Comment: But I suppose, either way, if I don't do anything (important) in OnPreExecute() I will be fine anyway since doInBackground() is blocking.